# Why use Variable() in inference?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, image-classification

I am learning PyTorch for an image classification task, and I ran into code where someone used a PyTorch `Variable()` in their function for prediction:

```
def predict_image(image):
    image_tensor = test_transforms(image).float()
    image_tensor = image_tensor.unsqueeze_(0)
    input = Variable(image_tensor)
    input = input.to(device)
    output = model(input)
    index = output.data.cpu().numpy().argmax()
    return index
```

Why do they use `Variable()` here? (even though it works fine without it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely omit it. Variables are a legacy component of PyTorch, [now deprecated](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html), that used to be required for autograd:

> #### `Variable` (deprecated)
>
> WARNING
>
> The `Variable` API has been deprecated: Variables are no longer necessary to use autograd with tensors. Autograd automatically supports Tensors with `requires_grad` set to `True`. Below please find a quick guide on what has changed:
>
> - `Variable(tensor)` and `Variable(tensor, requires_grad)` still work as expected, but they return Tensors instead of Variables.